# windows 7 welcome screen picture

Tags: windows

we have presently windows7 enterprise edition workstations and connected with windows 2003 domain controller wee need to apply our company logo on welcome screen picture through group policy is there any way to do this kindly require your support on this.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to deploy this by group policy to all your machines, your best bet will be to create a script to make the necessary changes, and push that script out to all your machines.

First, create the image you want to use for your custom login screen. **All images you generate must be no larger than 250KB**. Save the image at the following resolutions, and name them accordingly:

- backgroundDefault.jpg
- background768x1280.jpg
- background900x1440.jpg
- background960x1280.jpg
- background1024x1280.jpg
- background1280x1024.jpg
- background1024x768.jpg
- background1280x960.jpg
- background1600x1200.jpg
- background1440x900.jpg
- background1920x1200.jpg
- background1280x768.jpg
- background1360x768.jpg

If a computer's display isn't one of the above resolutions, the nearest resolution with the same aspect ratio will be used.

These files must be saved to `%WINDIR%\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds`, which does not exist by default. The script you create should make that directory:

```
mkdir %WINDIR%\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds
```

Then copy all of those images from your server to the directory:

```
robocopy "\\servername\share\dir" "%WINDIR%\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds"
```

Note that this script must be executed with full (elevated) privileges, since this is a system folder. Once the files are copied over, to allow systems to use a custom background, enable to following group policy setting: `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System > Logon >> Always use custom logon background`.

Once these settings are all in place, the custom login background should appear the next time the computer user logs off or the computer is restarted.

Comment: +1 for actually including the entire solution in your answer, rather than just linking. Small addendum though, I would suggest using `robocopy` rather than `xcopy` in case something goes wrong it can handle things better: `robocopy "\\servername\share\dir" "%WINDIR%\System32\oobe\info\backgrounds"`

Comment: @Farseeker, excellent suggestion; thanks. I use robocopy regularly, but forgot that it's included by default in Windows 7, since I always had to install it manually in XP.

Answer (score 2):

What you want to change is called the logon desktop. Check the following article for how to do that with group policies:

[Windows 7 Lets You Change the Logon Background Image](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-7-lets-you-change-the-logon-background-image/)

Related: [Windows 7 to officially support logon UI background customization](http://www.withinwindows.com/2009/03/15/windows-7-to-officially-support-logon-ui-background-customization/)

Answer (score 0):

We do this where I work, but we found that with scripts, if something goes wrong during execution the machines can end up in an inconsistent state.  Instead we rolled a small MSI package that's rolled out as a Computer GPO.  There are freeware MSI generators out there that can handle this (not linked to avoid accusations of solicitation; GIYF).